# 3D Peek and Pop memory leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, memory-leaks, 3dtouch

After implementing peek and pop I saw a problem that the controller that register a view for previewing not release the view after view is deallocated.
I have created a simple project with a tableView, and viewController register each cell as previewing as follow:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PeekCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kPeekCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self registerForPreviewingWithDelegate:self sourceView:cell];

    return cell;
}
```

the problem is if i scroll up and down as the cell will be released and new cell will be created. The viewController will register new cell for previewing and in this manner the memory is growing.
**Q:** What i'm doing wrong ? when should i call `unregisterForPreviewingWithContext` ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of registering for `previewing` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, try out:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    self.previewingContext = [self registerForPreviewingWithDelegate:self sourceView:cell];
} 

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
    [self unregisterForPreviewingWithContext:self.previewingContext];
}
```

Comment: nope , this is not a solution because in your example i will always store the 'previewingContext' for the last displayed cell, so i guess the better way is to add an array with 'previewingContext' and unregister in `didEndDisplayingCell` for `indexPath`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the array solution that you suggested in the @ystack comments, you can define UIViewControllerPreviewing in your cell
inside CellClass :

```
var viewControllerPreviewing : UIViewControllerPreviewing? = nil
```

inside tableView or CollectionView 
cell for row method

```
    if cell.viewControllerPreviewing != nil {
        unregisterForPreviewing(withContext: cell.viewControllerPreviewing!)
    }

    cell.viewControllerPreviewing = self.regist3DTouch(cell:cell)
```

and this is the regist3DTouch method

```
func regist3DTouch(cell:UIView)->UIViewControllerPreviewing?{
    if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == UIForceTouchCapability.available {
        return registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: (cell))
    }else{
        print("UIForceTouchCapability is not available")
        return nil
    }
}
```

hope it will help